# Getting Internal server error while submitting job to Apache Flink's dash board

Tags: java, apache-flink, stream-processing

I'm trying to run Apache Flink job in local environment, When I submit the jar, I'm getting Internal server error. I looked into log files, but couldn't find any information regarding this.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: You don't see anything in the JobManager's log?

Comment: Are you using a FAT jar ?

Comment: You can see the error's stack trace in Jobmanager's log when errors like that happen

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the logs in `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_{application_id}/container_{container_id}/jobmanager.log`